# How do you cut a single crystal into one of a different orientation?

Tags: crystals, x-ray-crystallography, diamond

I am reading about laser-cutting of single crystal wafers to produce wafers of a different orientation.

Is this as simple as cutting along the plane of the desired orientation? Meaning: with a 100 oriented diamond, as in this image, a vertical cut would inherently produce a new wafer with 110 oriented faces? [image]